# How to make raspbian load the spi module on boot up?

Tags: raspbian, spi

I do not know device tree well and good. I have enabled `spi` through `sudo raspi-config` and then checked `/boot/config.txt` which includes `dtparam=spi=on`.

Then I checked `lsmod | grep spi`. It shows

```
spi_bcm2835            7596   0
spidev                 7373   0
```

Also checked `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf` which is **blank**.

I have read a blog which suggested that `spi-dev` must include in `/etc/modules` to load `spi`. I got `i2c-dev` rather than that. I read [How to make raspbian load the i2c-dev module on boot up](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/how-to-make-raspbian-load-the-i2c-dev-module-on-boot-up) also. I noticed some where that suggested **not to load both of `spi` and `i2c` at the same time**. That's why I have commented `i2c-dev` at `/etc/modules` and added `spi-dev`. Then there is an error like that says unable to load module `spi-dev`.

> Question:

From **`spi-dev`** and **`spidev`** which one should I added to `/etc/modules`?

Somebody please help me if you got any useful tutorial about `spi` for beginners.

> Notice:

For more about the problem please a look at [How to check whether SPI working or not?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69582/how-to-check-whether-spi-working-or-not)

> Output:

```
spi mode: 0
bits per word: 8
max speed: 80000 Hz (80 KHz)

00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 0C 
00 0C 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00
```

The above output is generated for `./spidev_test -D /dev/spidev0.0 -s 80000`. Is this working (look there are two `0C` & sometimes all are `00`)?

Comment: I don't know of any problem with loading SPI and I2C at the same time and all that needs to be done is enabling them through sudo raspi-config. You may want to mention that you are doing some kind of custom system, as this would explain why you are having these issues. The regular system works - your modifications don''t your problems with this are all of your own making.

Answer (score 2):

To enable SPI just add the line `dtparam=spi=on` to `/boot/config.txt`.  **Nothing else is required.**

You should see the SPI devices in `/dev` after boot (try `ls /dev/spi*`).

I2C needs a similar device tree entry in /boot/config.txt **AND** the line `i2c-dev` in `/etc/modules`.

There is no problem in loading and using I2C and SPI at the same time.  They use different GPIO.

Comment: I got `spidev0.0` & `spidev0.1` as before. But the output of `spi` is `00`. According to http://www.brianhensley.net/2012/07/getting-spi-working-on-raspberry-pi.html device is not working. What do you think? @joan

Comment: @Johir I think you are not reading/writing the device properly.  Start a new question and give a code listing and a photo of your connections.